# SAS macros to average between a range of dates with missing dates in the data

Tags: sas

I'm completely new to SAS and its macros. I have this dataset, named mydata:

```
Obs SYMBOL  DATE    kx  y
1   A   20120128    5   6
2   B   20120128    10  7
3   C   20120128    20  9
4   D   20120128    6   10
5   E   20120128    9   20
```

My problem is to find this function:

```
Newi = ∑ j€[-10,-2]  (x+y)i,j /N,
```

where,

```
i = any random date(user defined)

-10 and -2(10 days or 2 days before i)

N= total number of days with data available for (x+y) between (-10,-2)
```

There can be missing dates in the available data.

Can anyone help me with the possible SAS macros for the following problem.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Your function definition is not very clear. Please could you post a few worked examples?

I think what you're saying is that for any given date, you want the average of (x+y) from 10 to 2 days leading up to that date, ignoring rows with missing dates. Do you want to create a dataset with the value of your function for every date in mydata?

Comment: just to add, I have another column with unique id's. This unique id can be same for different dates but cant occur twice for a single date. what I want is the average of (x+y) from 10  to 2 days by this unique id column. Yes, I want to create a dataset with the value of my function for every date I specify in mydata. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your date data are stored as dates and can accept numeric calculations. I'm also assuming that you want to get average of X and Y for a particular date around d, where d is user defined. Last, I'm assuming that if you have two unique ids on the same day, you keep the first one at random. Obviously those assumptions might need to be tweaked a bit but, from what I believe you are asking (I confess I'm only mostly sure I understand your question), hopefully this is close enough to what you need that you can tweak the rest pretty easily.

Okay...

```
 PROC SORT DATA in;
 BY date uniqueid;
 RUN;

%MACRO summarize( userdate );

DATA out;
SET in (where = (date >= &userdate -10 and date <= &userdate - 2);
BY date uniqueid;
xy = sum(x, y)
IF first.uniqueid;
RUN;

PROC SUMMARY DATA = out; 
OUTPUT OUT = Averages&userdate MEAN(xy) = ;
RUN;
%MEND summarize;

%summarize('20120128'd);
```

What's going on here? Well, I sort the data first by date and uniqueid. I could use NODUPKEY, but I imagine you might want to control how duplicate uniqueids on a given date are handled. The dataset is throwing out the dups by keeping the first one that it comes across, but you could modify deduping logic (which is coming from the BY command in the DATA step and the IF first. command in the same).

You want a set of dates around a particular user-defined date, d. So get d and filter the dataset with WHERE. You could also do this in your PROC SORT step, and there might be reasons for doing so if your raw data will be updated frequently. If you don't need the run the sort every time a user defines a date range, keep it outside the macro and only run it when needed. Sorts can be slow.

In the data step, I'm getting sum(x,y) to account for the fact that either x or y might be missing, or both, or neither. x + y would return missing in those cases. I assume that's now what you want, but do keep in mind that we'll be averaging out sum(x,y) over N, where N is "either x or y is not missing."  If you wanted to ignore those rows entirely, use x + y and add IF xy != . in your DATA step.

The last part, the sum, should be pretty self-explanatory.

Hope this helps.